# How to make symbolic breakpoint for all push segues?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, debugging, segue

I'm currently debugging my app, and have an issue where a segue is being performed, but I can't for the life of me figure out where it is being called from.

I was wondering if it was possible to add a breakpoint so the app will pause and show the line where it is being called from?

I tried to add a symbolic breakpoint, but couldn't get it working.

Comment: You can do it with method swizzling or with simple category for UIViewController which will implement prepareForSegue:.

Comment: Try `- [UIStoryboardSegue perform]`

Comment: @Cy-4AH OK, this got it to break, but I have that strange hard to understand debugging screen. Like this:

`UIKit - [UIStoryboardSegue perform]:
->  0x10a1f8bfa <+0>:   pushq  %rbp
    0x10a1f8bfb <+1>:   movq   %rsp, %rbp
    0x10a1f8bfe <+4>:   pushq  %r15`

Is it possible to see where the line is being called from?

Comment: @Cy-4AH Looking at the stack from the side panel, it says it's being called from UIApplicationMain...why would that be? Another segue shows the view controller that is calling it.

Comment: There is should be call stack in debug navigator. You can also print stack by typing `bt` in debug console.

Comment: @Cy-4AH - stack navigator shows UIApplicationMain although another one shows the ViewController where it was called from.

Comment: Try `- [UIViewController performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:]`

Comment: Gah, got it. I traced it back to a triggered segue back in the storyboard. Thanks a million. You're a star :)

Answer (score 1):

Create category for UIViewController and add that to it:

```
+ (void)load {
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        Class class = [self class];

        SEL originalSelector = @selector(prepareForSegue:sender:);
        SEL swizzledSelector = @selector(yd_prepareForSegue:sender:);

        Method originalMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(class, originalSelector);
        Method swizzledMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(class, swizzledSelector);

        BOOL didAddMethod = class_addMethod(class, originalSelector, method_getImplementation(swizzledMethod), method_getTypeEncoding(swizzledMethod));

        if (didAddMethod) {
            class_replaceMethod(class, swizzledSelector, method_getImplementation(originalMethod), method_getTypeEncoding(originalMethod));
        } else {
            method_exchangeImplementations(originalMethod, swizzledMethod);
        }
    });
}

- (void)yd_prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    [self yd_prepareForSegue:segue sender:sender];
    NSLog(@"prepareForSegue From: %@", self);
}
```